# Passing JSON to Jade from Node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug

JSON passed to template engine, Jade:

```
[ { _id: 531fb4f6ae8a7ad5a58c65fa,
    goals: 'adsfasdfasdfas',
    exam: 'asdfasdf',
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 531fb5cadd70a399a6ed1213,
    goals: 'asdfasdfasdf',
    exam: 'adsf',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

The Jade template:

```
h1 Listings
for i in data
  #{i.exam}
```

The output:

```
---empty space---
```

I can output #{i} just fine.
I'm getting rather frustrated with Jade and wondering if I should go back to Django, which is super forgiving.  Anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add a html tag to the Jade template:

```
h1 Listings
for i in data
  p #{i.exam}
```

Comment: This was the answer, thank you so much.  Would up-vote this if I could.  Apparently, Jade won't let you output the nested JSON objects without including the HTML tag, even just to see the output.

Answer (score 1):

If you need show datas without html tags, use `|` symbol;

example:

```
h1 Listings
for i in data
  | #{i.exam}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't define 'data'. try this:

```
{
   data:
  [
    {
        _id: '531fb4f6ae8a7ad5a58c65fa',
        goals: 'adsfasdfasdfas',
        exam: 'asdfasdf',
        __v: 0 
      }
  ]
}
```

and make sure the value of String enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Hey thanks! Data was defined as the output listed above.  Turns out the response listed below solved my problem.